# Placeholder - Not support in operamobile - Jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

The text box place holder does not support in the OperaMobile10.0. But Its working fine with safari. How to solve this one?

Please help me.

THanks in advance.

Comment: Could you set up an example on jsiddle or something? Would save me some time...

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem with the browser. The attribute `placeholder`is a HTML5 attribute, which is also not supported by Internet Explorer 9 in the latest version.

Comment: I only wanna tell, that more browsers does not support `placeholder`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('input[type=text]').focus(function(){ 
    if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultValue'))
    {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });

  $('input[type=text]').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
      $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultValue'));
    } 
  });
});
```

http://pinoytech.org/question/4595584/how-can-i-improve-this-basic-jquery-code